# How to detect iOS settings screen and pop up a UIView

Tags: ios, iphone, settings

I want a password protected settings screen for iOS. For that when the user navigates to the settings screen I hope to popup a UIView and ask for the password. For that I want to know two things

1. How to detect the user has moved to the settings screen.
2. How to pop up my UIView(or else at lest an alertview) within the settings screen.

Comment: Nope. Not gonna happen. Apple wants the user to control the phone, not the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible, your app works on its own scope, you cannot monitor or control in any way what the user does in the phone outside of your app.

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer is: you can't. Incorporate the protected settings within the app.